# EnableAutoConfiguration in a common module for autowire the jacksonObjectMapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I am using a spring boot 2.x with multi java modules (in IntelliJ) and in **a Common module** I am trying to @Autowire on ObjectMapper

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("myBean")
public Jdbi getJDBIwrite(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource, 
ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return getJdbi(dataSource, objectMapper);
}
```

As obviously the *org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration* is not in my base dir path it fails to auto wire.

When using below

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class JdbiConfiguration {
. . .
```

It works fine.

1. Is there another better way to deal with this with other annotation or design?
2. Without the *EnableAutoConfiguration* It really only being complained in IntelliJ, but compilation build and run time works fine.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, it seems that you can use either one of the annotations below:

```
`@Import(JacksonConfiguration.class)`
`@DependsOn({"jacksonObjectMapper"})`
```

where above is defined as below:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

@Bean
public JacksonObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper(){ ...
```